# Combine both stereo channels into mono?

Tags: android, audio

I combed the [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) and couldn't find any API or setting to switch from stereo to mono (both channels having a signal that's the sum of the two stereo channels).

Is it possible at all to accomplish this in Android?

Comment: did you found a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a method in the AudioManager class called [`setParameters`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setParameters%28java.lang.String%29) that *might* do that. Unfortunately, the API is not very clear about what it does:

> ```
> public void setParameters (String keyValuePairs)
> ```
>
> Sets a variable number of parameter values to audio hardware.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *keyValuePairs* list of parameters key value pairs in the form: key1=value1;key2=value2;...

If we look at the source code for this method in AudioManager.java:

```
/**
 * Sets a variable number of parameter values to audio hardware.
 *
 * @param keyValuePairs list of parameters key value pairs in the form:
 *    key1=value1;key2=value2;...
 *
 */
public void setParameters(String keyValuePairs) {
    AudioSystem.setParameters(keyValuePairs);
}
```

And looking at AudioSystem.java:

```
/*
 * Sets a group generic audio configuration parameters. The use of these parameters
 * are platform dependant, see libaudio
 *
 * param keyValuePairs  list of parameters key value pairs in the form:
 *    key1=value1;key2=value2;...
 */
public static native int setParameters(String keyValuePairs);
```

Not much information there. It looks like the parameters might be hardware-specific, and I'm not even sure the parameters would do what you're looking to do.

Are you trying to set this system-wide or just in one app? I assumed system-wide, but if that's not the case, I'd imagine it would be easier.

Comment: +1 already for your research. I will have to test this before accepting. Answering your question, yes system-wide.

Answer (score 0):

There's been an open issue on this for Android for the last three years, but no response from Google on it yet:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17337

If you have rooted your device and installed BusyBox, you can use the Boeffla Sound Control app off of the Google Play store.